# When do we (or when do we not) allow concurrent modification when using ListIterator?

Tags: java, concurrentmodification, listiterator

For instance, let's say there is a some `Collections#reverse(List)` operation that uses the `ListIterator` as such:

```
var forwardItr = list.listIterator();
var reverseItr = list.listIterator(list.size());
while (forwardItr.nextIndex() < reverseItr.previousIndex()) {
  var forward = forwardItr.next();
  var reverse = reverseItr.previous();
  forwardItr.set(reverse)
  reverseItr.set(forward)
}
```

Should there ever be some implementation that throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` from `ListIterator#set`? Or rather, is there a *particular* type of modification (i.e. "structural") that should cause an exception throw? Is it implied that some implementations of `List` may justifiably throw an exception from the aforementioned operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should there ever be some implementation that throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` from `ListIterator::set`?

The answer is that there *could* be.

The javadocs for `List`, `ListIterator` and `ConcurrentModificationException` talk it terms of modifications that are *permissible* and *not permissible* without going into the specifics of what is permissible.  If you look at the javadocs for (say) `ArrayList` you will see that it says that changes that don't cause structural modifications are permissible during an iteration.  However, that doesn't apply to all list types; e.g. all modifications are permitted during an iteration for a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

A custom list type could place *different* constraints on modifications.

> Or rather, is there a particular type of modification (i.e. "structural") that should cause an exception throw?

Well `ListIterator::set` is not a structural modification.   But for some list classes a "structural" modification during iteration will lead to a CME.

Other (hypothetical) examples:

- A custom list class *could* be implemented that did not permit `set` operations if (say) two iterators were active, and throw a CME if this happened.
- In a custom list that was a sorted view of something else, a  `set` call that broke the ordering could throw a CME.

Arguable these *could* be a different exceptions; e.g. `UnsupportedOperationException`.  My reading of the javadocs are that CME *would* be appropriate.

> Is it implied that some implementations of `List` may justifiably throw an exception from the aforementioned operation?

Yes.  A custom `List` implementation could do all sorts of "interesting" things so long as it conforms to the behaviors defined in the `List` and `Collection` APIs.

---

Q: Do you need to allow for this in your code?

A: IMO is reasonable to write your code so that it works for "normal" lists.  It is not possible to allow for all of the crazy things that a custom list class might do.

Comment: I appreciate your speedy response. I'd typically want to use best practices to the best of my ability, and checking for concurrent modification seems generally encouraged; though whether or not to check seems to require greater-than-basic judgment.

Comment: Checking for CME is probably a bad idea.   If it occurs, it indicates that there is a fault in the program as a while.  You can't recover from it in this code.  Therefore testing for it in this code is the wrong thing to do.  (Allowing an *unexpected* unchecked exception to propagate is *good* practice ...)

Comment: Forgive me; I meant to convey what you have stated in parenthesis: (Allowing an unexpected unchecked exception to propagate is good practice ...)

Comment: Also ... can I encourage you to read this: http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/27.  The take-away should be that looking for "best practice" or "good practice" dogma that you can follow without thinking is misguided.    You need to understand the issues, and then work out *for your self* what is appropriate in each specific context.  (And sometimes, the most appropriate thing can be to ignore *good practice* advice.)

Comment: OK, I mis-understood you; but ... *"and checking for concurrent modification seems generally encouraged"* - I have **do not recall** ever seeing someone say that application code should check for CMEs.  And I have **do not recall** ever seeing anyone "encouraging" custom list implementers to do this.  Do you have examples?